# How to use doPACE in lib JMRTD 0.6.0?

Tags: java

How to get the stdDomainParam parameter in JMRTD 0.6.0? In the later versions JMRTD it was:

```
try {
    CardAccessFile cardAccessFile = new CardAccessFile(service.getInputStream(PassportService.EF_CARD_ACCESS));
    Collection<PACEInfo> paceInfos = cardAccessFile.getPACEInfos();
    if (paceInfos != null && paceInfos.size() > 0) {
        PACEInfo paceInfo = paceInfos.iterator().next();
        service.doPACE(bacKey, paceInfo.getObjectIdentifier(), PACEInfo.toParameterSpec(paceInfo.getParameterId()));
        paceSucceeded = true;
    } else {
        paceSucceeded = true;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w(TAG, e);
}
```

In the latest version of the CardAccessFile returns only SecurityInfo.getProtocolOIDString() and SecurityInfo.getObjectIdentifier()

```
CardAccessFile cardAccessFile = new CardAccessFile(passportService.getInputStream(PassportService.EF_CARD_ACCESS));
Collection<SecurityInfo> securityInfos = cardAccessFile.getSecurityInfos();
SecurityInfo securityInfo = securityInfos.iterator().next();
passportService.doPACE(bacKey, securityInfo.getObjectIdentifier(), PACEInfo.toParameterSpec(?????) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<PACEInfo> paceInfos = new ArrayList<PACEInfo>();

        if (securityInfos == null) {
            return paceInfos;
        }

        for (SecurityInfo securityInfo: securityInfos) {
            if (securityInfo instanceof PACEInfo) {
                paceInfos.add((PACEInfo)securityInfo);
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Looks familiar](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmrtd/discussion/580232/thread/5af01545/#c3f0).

Comment: In Java 8 you can probably do some stream / lambda tricks to do this in a one-liner.

Comment: The question was how to do doPACE. Since it requires AlgorithmParameterSpecs and PACEInfo doesn't contain stdDomainParam

Answer (score 0):

tested & working ...

```
CardAccessFile cardAccessFile = new 
CardAccessFile(service.getInputStream(PassportService.EF_CARD_ACCESS));
Collection<SecurityInfo> securityInfos = cardAccessFile.getSecurityInfos();
SecurityInfo securityInfo = securityInfos.iterator().next();
List<PACEInfo> paceInfos = new ArrayList<>();
if (securityInfo instanceof PACEInfo) {
    paceInfos.add((PACEInfo) securityInfo);
}
```